# .NET 6 E2E tests with test server fail on TeamCity CI, but work run manually

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .NET 6 app (with ASP.NET Core web part). I use [cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) for E2E testing. After we migrated to .NET 6 from .NET Framework, I wanted to run E2E cypress tests on the web application.

My process is that I actually run nUnit tests in C# that initialize the in-memory SQLite database and then use this database connection for my app. I use such an approach to create data needed for E2E tests before the actual tests are run. Then I run cypress from C# unit test. This all worked fine in .NET Framework, where the web application was actually run during the tests, so it was available on a real URL within IIS.

With .NET 6, we have `WebApplicationFactory` [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactory-1?view=aspnetcore-6.0) that allows running the app in-memory. However, I wanted my web application to be available under a real URL with a real port, so I can launch cypress tests against it.

After exploring various ideas from [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4892), I created a factory of real test apps (with real IP and port):

```cs
public abstract class RealTestServerWebAppFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
{
    private bool _disposed;
    private IHost _host;

    public RealTestServerWebAppFactory()
    {
        ClientOptions.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        ClientOptions.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost");
    }
    
    public string ServerAddress
    {
        get
        {
            EnsureServer();
            return ClientOptions.BaseAddress.ToString();
        }
    }
    
    public override IServiceProvider Services
    {
        get
        {
            EnsureServer();
            return _host!.Services!;
        }
    }
    
    // Code created with advices from https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4892
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);
        
        // Final port will be dynamically assigned
        builder.UseUrls("http://127.0.0.1:0");
        
        builder.ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices);
    }
    
    protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        // Create the host for TestServer now before we
        // modify the builder to use Kestrel instead.
        var testHost = builder.Build();

        // Modify the host builder to use Kestrel instead
        // of TestServer so we can listen on a real address.
        builder.ConfigureWebHost(webHostBuilder => webHostBuilder.UseKestrel());

        // Create and start the Kestrel server before the test server,
        // otherwise due to the way the deferred host builder works
        // for minimal hosting, the server will not get "initialized
        // enough" for the address it is listening on to be available.
        // See https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/33846.
        _host = builder.Build();
        _host.Start();

        // Extract the selected dynamic port out of the Kestrel server
        // and assign it onto the client options for convenience so it
        // "just works" as otherwise it'll be the default http://localhost
        // URL, which won't route to the Kestrel-hosted HTTP server.
        var server = _host.Services.GetRequiredService<IServer>();
        var addresses = server.Features.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>();

        ClientOptions.BaseAddress = addresses!.Addresses
            .Select(x => new Uri(x))
            .Last();

        // Return the host that uses TestServer, rather than the real one.
        // Otherwise the internals will complain about the host's server
        // not being an instance of the concrete type TestServer.
        // See https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/34702.
        testHost.Start();
        return testHost;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);

        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _host?.Dispose();
            }

            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

    protected abstract void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services);

    /// <summary>
    /// Makes sure that the server has actually been run.
    /// It must be executed at lest once to have the address and port assigned and the app fully working
    /// </summary>
    private void EnsureServer()
    {
        if (_host is null)
        {
            using var _ = CreateDefaultClient();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I create a class deriving from `RealTestServerWebAppFactory`, where I set up some test dependency injection, but this nothing important for our example. Let's call this child class `MyServerTestApp`.

An instance creation in the tests looks as follows:

```cs
var serverTestApp = new MyServerTestApp();
serverTestApp.ServerAddress;
```

At the second line, `EnsureServer()` method is called which creates a default client for the app. It also calls `CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)` from `RealTestServerWebAppFactory` class which does all the magic. Locally, after this line I have the URL for the app and I can access it via a web browser (or E2E tests).

Now, the problem is that the tests work fine locally. However, I also execute them on CI - TeamCity to be more precise. The `dotnet test` command used to run those tests by TeamCity looks as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" test C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c9a5fb5bca7f6666\Tests\E2ETests\bin\Release\net6.0-windows\MyApp.E2ETests.dll /logger:logger://teamcity /TestAdapterPath:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnet\tools\vstest15 /logger:console;verbosity=normal
```

which is in fact quite straightforward use of `dotnet test` command. However, these tests fail executed by TeamCity with the following exception:

```
[12:47:54][dotnet test] A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
[12:47:56][dotnet test] NUnit Adapter 4.2.0.0: Test execution started
[12:47:56][dotnet test] Running all tests in C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c9a5fb5bca7f6666\Tests\E2ETests\bin\Release\net6.0-windows\MyApp.E2ETests.dll
[12:47:58][dotnet test]    NUnit3TestExecutor discovered 10 of 10 NUnit test cases using Current Discovery mode, Non-Explicit run
[12:48:07][dotnet test] Setup failed for test fixture MyApp.E2ETests.SomeTestsClass
[12:48:07][dotnet test] System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains no elements
[12:48:07][dotnet test] StackTrace:    at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowNoElementsException()
[12:48:07][dotnet test]    at System.Linq.Enumerable.Last[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
[12:48:07][dotnet test]    at MyApp.E2ETests.Infrastructure.RealTestServerWebAppFactory`1.CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder) in C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c9a5fb5bca7f6666\Tests\MyApp.E2ETests\Infrastructure\RealTestServerWebAppFactory.cs:line 85
[12:48:07][dotnet test]    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.ConfigureHostBuilder(IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
[12:48:07][dotnet test]    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.EnsureServer()
[12:48:07][dotnet test]    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateDefaultClient(DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
[12:48:07][dotnet test]    at MyApp.E2ETests.Infrastructure.RealTestServerWebAppFactory`1.EnsureServer() in C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c9a5fb5bca7f6666\Tests\MyApp.E2ETests\Infrastructure\RealTestServerWebAppFactory.cs:line 122
[12:48:07][dotnet test]    at MyApp.E2ETests.Infrastructure.RealTestServerWebAppFactory`1.get_ServerAddress() in C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c9a5fb5bca7f6666\Tests\MyApp.E2ETests\Infrastructure\RealTestServerWebAppFactory.cs:line 35
System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains no elements
```

It seems that this code:

```cs
var addresses = server.Features.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>();
```

returns an empty connection of addresses being run by TeamCity. As a consequence, this code:

```cs
ClientOptions.BaseAddress = addresses!.Addresses
            .Select(x => new Uri(x))
            .Last();
```

fails with `System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains no elements`.

What's weird is that if I run those tests using the same `dotnet test` command as TeamCity does manually using `cmd`, it works. It works on the same CI machine, but executed manually from `cmd`, not as TeamCity's build step. The CI machine runs Windows Server 2019.

I've been thinking it might be something related to the rights/permissions of the user used for running TeamCity. However, the Windows Service for TeamCity uses "Local System" account, so it should have all permissions as far as I know.

Any help/ideas are appreciated :)

Comment: Could it be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546843/iserveraddressesfeature-addresses-empty-when-running-under-dotnet-exe)?

Comment: wow, thanks for that link! It seems it works! I've seen it before, but was not sure which value to use as DefaultAddress. I just generated a random port and construct the URL manually in case addresses are not present. Do you want to post your answer or should I self-answer with code example? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48547597/4919526), you have to set the default address on `IServerAddressesFeature` using the following code:

```cs
var serverFeatures = featureCollection.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>();
if (serverFeatures.Addresses.Count == 0)
{
    ListenOn(DefaultAddress); // Start the server on the default address
    serverFeatures.Addresses.Add(DefaultAddress) // Add the default address to the IServerAddressesFeature
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works :) I'll just add that for "DefaultAddress" I just used a randomly generated address. This is how it looks: https://gist.github.com/mm-dsibinski/13d44f747301899e2dcb602fe450ce7d