# Use WebApplicationFactory to test CoreWCF endpoints with AutoFac DI

Tags: integration-testing, autofac, corewcf

I have a CoreWCF project with Autofac DI and I want to create some Integration Tests using a custom WebApplicationfactory.
I have used the custom WebApplicationFactory code for Autofac suggested here

https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/1207 by Alistair Evans

This works fine for WebApi endpoints but it does not work for my CoreWCF endpoints.

What I found was that the Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer that is created does not define the Features property with any IServerAddressesFeature.  This causes a problem when the CoreWCF.ServiceObjectModel ApplyConfiguration is executed.

I have got around this by using reflection to set the Features property in the CreateServiceProvider method of the CustomServiceProviderFactory as shown below but does anybody know if there is a better way around this.

```
    /// Enables in-memory integration testing for CoreWCF (outside-in testing via <see cref="HttpClient"/>).
    ///
    /// Use these tests to exercise the entire HTTP stack, rather than create in-process ServiceModel channels.
    /// 
    /// <see href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1"/>
    /// <seealso href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.1"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TStartup"></typeparam>
    public class WcfWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
    {
        private ILifetimeScope _container;
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureTestContainer<ContainerBuilder>(container =>
            {
                container.RegisterBuildCallback(BuildCallback);
            });
            builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {
            });
        }
        private void BuildCallback(ILifetimeScope obj)
        {
            _container = obj;
        }
        protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.UseServiceProviderFactory(new CustomServiceProviderFactory(ClientOptions.BaseAddress.ToString()));
            return base.CreateHost(builder);
        }
        protected override IHostBuilder? CreateHostBuilder()
        {
            return base.CreateHostBuilder();
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Based upon https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14907#issuecomment-620750841 - only necessary because of an issue in ASP.NET Core
    /// </summary>
    public class CustomServiceProviderFactory : IServiceProviderFactory<ContainerBuilder>
    {
        private readonly string _testServerBaseAddress;
        private AutofacServiceProviderFactory _wrapped;
        private IServiceCollection _services;


        public CustomServiceProviderFactory(string testServerBaseAddress)
        {
            _testServerBaseAddress = testServerBaseAddress;
            _wrapped = new AutofacServiceProviderFactory();
        }

        public ContainerBuilder CreateBuilder(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Store the services for later.
            _services = services;
            return _wrapped.CreateBuilder(services);
        }

        public IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider(ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
        {
            var sp = _services.BuildServiceProvider();
#pragma warning disable CS0612 // Type or member is obsolete
            var filters = sp.GetRequiredService<IEnumerable<IStartupConfigureContainerFilter<ContainerBuilder>>>();
#pragma warning restore CS0612 // Type or member is obsolete
            foreach (var filter in filters)
            {
                filter.ConfigureContainer(b => { })(containerBuilder);
            }


            var serviceProvider = _wrapped.CreateServiceProvider(containerBuilder);

            // The CoreWCF.ServiceObjectModel ApplyConfiguration expects there to be at least one IServerAddressesFeature
            // This is normally present for the Kestrel webserver but for the TestServer in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost namespace does not seem to populate it
            // Had to use Refelction to set this since the Set method causes a containerBuilder Build operation
            var addresses = new ServerAddressesFeature();
            addresses.Addresses.Add(_testServerBaseAddress);
            var features = new FeatureCollection();
            features.Set<IServerAddressesFeature>(addresses);
            var testServer = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServer>();
            var field = typeof(TestServer).GetField("<Features>k__BackingField", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            field.SetValue(testServer, features);

            return serviceProvider;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found some clue in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48547597/3299257

Specifically in the [announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/224)

> **Hosting no longer adds default server address when no address is explicitly configured**
>
> The WebHost will no longer add the default server address of `http://localhost:5000` to the `IServerAddressesFeature` when none is specified. The configuration of the default server address will now be a responsibility of the server.
>
> Addresses specified in `IServerAddressesFeature` are intended to be used by servers as a fallback when no explicit address is specified directly.

Adding feature was discussed here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5931 and came to conclusion that it won't be implemented in `TestServer`.

In my test scenario I do not use full `WebApplicationFactory`, but rather directly utilize `TestServer` so I could make a simpler soultion:

```cs
var addresses = new ServerAddressesFeature();
addresses.Addresses.Add("http://localhost");
var features = new FeatureCollection();
features.Set<IServerAddressesFeature>(addresses);
return new TestServer(builder, features);
```

**In your scenario:**

(sorry, this is not verified), you could use [WebApplicationFactory.WithWebHostBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactory-1.withwebhostbuilder) and then, invoke [.UseTestServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.testhost.webhostbuilderextensions.usetestserver) constructing your own TestServer and providing feature collection in the second argument.

```cs
factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder => {
    var addresses = new ServerAddressesFeature();
    addresses.Addresses.Add("http://localhost");
    var features = new FeatureCollection();
    features.Set<IServerAddressesFeature>(addresses);
    builder.UseTestServer(new TestServer(builder, features));
});
```